# Group few JPA annotations into one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have following mapping in my entity:

```
@CollectionTable(name = "test_entity_data", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "test_entity_id"))
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "language", length = 10)
@MapKeyClass(Language.class)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
private Map<Language, String> data = new HashMap<>();
```

I have to use the same mapping in a few places in my code. Is there a way I could group those annotations into one? E.g. `@MultilangualData`?

Answer (score 0):

If using JPA 2.2 then you can use "meta annotations". This is basic Java, not specific to JPA. See [this blog post](https://datanucleus.wordpress.com/2017/05/25/dn-v5-1-meta-annotations/)

Comment: I can't because most of annotations I want to use are applicable to field not type

Comment: You can do meta annotations at field level or class level! That is what `@Target` is for. That links says `You can do the same thing ... for annotations on fields/methods.`

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own Custom Validator and use it in your entity.

Basically you create a new annotaion as below:

```
@Target( { ElementType.PACKAGE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MultilangualDataValidator.class)
public @interface MultilangualData{

    String message() default "MultilangualData validation failed";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And write a validator to validate all your conditions when this annotation is used:

```
public class MultilangualDataValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MultilangualData, String> {

    private MultilangualData multilangualData;

    public void initialize(MultilangualData constraintAnnotation) {
        this.multilangualData = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

        // Do your validation here.
    }

}
```

Referred from: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

Comment: How can I apply e.g `@MapKeyColumn` in a validator?

Comment: You can add validations in the isValid method as below:

`ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
  Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
  Set<ConstraintViolation<String>> constraints = validator
   .validate("<your felid value>");`

Comment: A "Bean Validation API" annotation is nothing at all to do with grouping JPA annotations into one single annotation to save typing. Heck, using JPA you don't even need to have Bean Validation enabled.